# Solution of the equation $f(ax) = bf(x)$

Tags: functional-equations

Given the equation $f(ax) = bf(x)$, with $a, b > 0$, demonstrate that the solution is: $$f(x) = g(\log x)x^{\frac{\log b}{\log a}}$$

where $g(x) = g(x + \log a)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with period $\log(a)$.

By the method of induction I arrived in the particular solution:

$f(x) = Cx^{\frac{\log b}{\log a}}$, where $C$ is an arbitrary constant (case $g(x) =$ constant).

But I could not demonstrate how to get in the generic solution with the associated periodic function $g(x)$. Can someone help me?

Comment: You probably want to specify $x > 0$ and $a > 0$.

Comment: Express $g$ in terms of $f$ and show that the functional equation for $f$ translates into a the functional equation for $g$ that expresses periodicity.

Comment: Expressing g in terms of f is from the assumption that there already exists a g(x). But this is not known at the beginning of the problem. That would be a check proof. The problem is how from the equation to arrive at the solution with g(x)?

Comment: @JaberMac is my answer no good for you?

Comment: @dcolazin Thank you! this is a brilliant check of an assigned function applied in the equation itself. But I did not understand how to set the $g(x) = f(e^x)/e^{Ax}$ definition? did you get the solution itself? we start from the equation that the solution is not known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $x > 0$

$$
f(a^{\log_a(ax)})-bf(a^{\log_a x}) = 0
$$

or

$$
F(\log_a x + 1)-bF(\log_a x) = 0
$$

or calling $u = \log_a x$

$$
F(u+1)-b F(u) = 0
$$

This is a difference functional equation with solution

$$
F(u) = \Phi(u)b^u
$$

where $\Phi(u)$ is any periodic function with period $1$

hence

$$
f(x) = \Phi(\log_a x)b^{\log_a x}=\Phi\left(\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}\right)b^{\frac{\log_a x}{\log_b x}\log_b x} = g(\ln x)x^{\frac{\ln b}{\ln a}}
$$

NOTE

Regarding the periodicity of $\Phi(u)$ we have

$$
\Phi(u) = \Phi(u+1)\to \Phi(\log_a x) = \Phi(\log_a x+1) \to \Phi\left(\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}\right) = \Phi\left(\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}+1\right)
$$

and finally

$$
\Phi(\ln x) = \Phi(\ln x+\ln a)
$$

Comment: Thank You! perfect explanation! now I see everything more clearly. sorry, I just did not understand something at the end: $\theta (lnx/lna) \equiv \theta´ (lnx)$, what does that mean?

Comment: Better and cleaner would be to make $\Phi\left(\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}\right) = g(\ln x)$

Comment: you understood perfectly what I needed. Thank you very much. But sorry for my ignorance. I'm still intrigued by the $\phi (lnx/lna)$ function. This function is equivalent to $g(lnx)$? By the proof $\phi (u)$ has period equal to 1. The function $g(lnx)$ has period equal to $ln(a)$ (by the solution of the problem). I am confused by the equivalence of these functions and their periods. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @JaberMac Please. See attached note.

Comment: Perfect! now I understand. If $\phi(lnx) = \phi(lnx + lna)$ then we can assume that $\phi(x) = \phi(x + lna)$, what is the function shown in the problem solution. Beautiful demonstration! Thank you so much again.

Comment: @JaberMac It is my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Hints can be useful if you are willingful to hear.

- Let $f$ be a solution of the equation, then define $g(x) = \frac{f(e^x)}{e^{Ax}}$, where $A = \frac{\log(b)}{\log(a)} = \log_a(b)$.

  $g(x)$ is periodic of period $\log(a)$: $$g(x+\log(a)) = \frac{f(e^{x+\log(a)})}{e^{Ax+A\log(a)}} = \frac{f(ae^{x})}{e^{Ax+\log(b)}} = \frac{bf(e^{x})}{be^{Ax}} = g(x)$$

So every solution can be written as $f(x) = g(\log(x))x^A$.

- Viceversa, an $f$ of the kind $f(x) = g(\log(x))x^A$ is a solution of the equation:

$$f(ax) = g(\log(ax))(ax)^A = g(\log(x)+\log(a))x^Aa^A = a^A f(x) = bf(x)$$

So all the $f(x) = g(\log(x))x^A$ are solutions.

Comment: Thank You! This is a brilliant check of an assigned function applied in the equation itself. But I did not understand how to set the definition $g(x) = f(e^x)/e^{Ax}$? Did you get the solution itself? we start from the equation that the solution is not known.